# microsoft band get id in sensor

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

My windows phone is connected to multiple bands. I want to read the sensor signals and record them for all bands. I wonder how to get the band id or name in the sensor_ReadingChanged method. Or is there some other approach? I'm using C#.

```
    async void sensor_ReadingChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Band.Sensors.BandSensorReadingEventArgs<Microsoft.Band.Sensors.IBandHeartRateReading> e)
    {
        string bandname = "" //how to get the name/id of the band
        string msg = bandname + "\theartrate\t" + e.SensorReading.Timestamp.ToString() + "\t" + e.SensorReading.HeartRate.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        await SendSignal(msg); //record heart rate from this band
    }
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question... but the naming convention you have used for your method is giving me heart pulp palpitations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using reflection to discover the identity of the band; something like:

```
        _bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.ReadingChanged += async (obj, ev) =>
        {
            var type = obj.GetType();
            var props = type.GetRuntimeProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "ClientHandle").First();
            var bc = (IBandClient)props.GetValue(obj);

            // compare with cached band client references
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(bc, _bandClient))
            {
            }
        }
```